# Fixed margin to element on the left side

Tags: html, css, position, margin

I have to icons in my website. I want to have a fixed separation between them although the screen size changes. Theire position will vary but I want that separation keeps unmodified.

```
<i class="material-icons" id="menu-toggle">menu</i>
<i class="material-icons" id="menu-text">face</i>

#menu-toggle{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

#menu-text{

    margin-left:90px;
   margin-top: 5%;
}
```

Playing with it, I've been able to move the icons so they don't overlap, but this is not what I need. I want them to change their position but maintaining the separation between them.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 1. edit your question, be specific
2. add a `jsfiddle`

Answer (score 0):

Use a divider!

Create one like this:

```
.divider{
    width:50px;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and then insert it between the elements so that they maintain a constant spacing between them of the width of the divider. You could also establish a set percentage of the available screen space as a way to keep them relative to the display.

```
<div style="text-align: center"> 
    <asp:Icon ID="Icon1" "Width="90px"/>
    <div class="divider"/>
    <asp:Icon ID="Icon2" "Width="90px"/>
</div>
```

Just use a percentage to keep them a safe distance away from the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wz9nhd3/1/)

```
i{

margin-top: 5%;
margin-left:10%;
```

}